# How to update parent state array from child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

```
App
|
|----|---------------------|
     |                     |
     RadioInputForm        TextInputForm
```

I am trying to update arrays in my parent state with data from the child components but the events are not firing. I have already tried previous solutions such as {() => callback()} and {() => callback.bind(this)}, but nothing seems to work.

Upon entering input a value at a specified index, an array in the parent state should be updated. How this will work is similar to a survey web app and you should be able to go back to a previous entry, hence the array.

Here is what I tried so far, any help will be appreciated:

```
// App.js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    let radioQuestions = [], textQuestions = [];
    let option = {id: "", options: {option1: false, option2: false, option3: false}, text: ""};

    for(var i = 0; i < data.questions.length; ++i) {
        textQuestions[i] = "";

        if(data.questions[i].question_type === "RadioQuestion") {
            radioQuestions[i] = option;
            radioQuestions[i].id = data.questions[i].id;
        } else radioQuestions[i] = {};
    }

    this.state = {
        textQuestions: textQuestions,
        radioQuestions: radioQuestions,
        index: 0
    };

    this.handleRadioSelect= this.handleRadioSelect.bind(this);
    this.handleRadioTextChange = this.handleRadioTextChange.bind(this);
    this.handleTextQuestionChange= this.handleTextQuestionChange.bind(this);
    this.handleBack = this.handleBack.bind(this);
    this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
}

handleRadioSelect(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const questions = this.state.radioQuestions.slice();
    const index = this.state.index;

    switch(value) {
        case "option1":
            if(questions[index].options.option1 === true)
                questions[index].options.option1 = false;
            else questions[index].options.option1 = true;
            break;
        case "option2":
            if(questions[index].options.option2 === true)
                questions[index].options.option2 = false;
            else questions[index].options.option2 = true;
            break;
        case "option3":
            if(questions[index].options.option3 === true)
                questions[index].options.option3 = false;
            else questions[index].options.option3 = true;
            break;
        default:
    }

    this.setState({
        radioQuestions: questions
    });
}

handleRadioTextChange(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;

    const questions = this.state.radioQuestions.slice()
    questions[this.state.index].text = value;

    this.setState({
        radioQuestions: questions
    })
}

handleTextQuestionChange(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;

    const answers = this.state.textAnswers.slice()
    answers[this.props.index] = value;

    this.setState({
        textAnswers: answers
    })
}
```

The child component with the Radio form:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        radioQuestions: this.props.radioQuestions
    }

    this.handleRadioTextChange = this.handleRadioTextChange.bind(this);
    this.handleRadioSelect = this.handleRadioSelect.bind(this);
}

handleRadioSelect(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const questions = this.state.radioQuestions.slice();
    const index = this.state.index;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(questions[index]));

    switch(value) {
        case "option1":
            if(questions[index].options.option1 === true)
                questions[index].options.option1 = false;
            else questions[index].options.option1 = true;
            break;
        case "option2":
            if(questions[index].options.option2 === true)
                questions[index].options.option2 = false;
            else questions[index].options.option2 = true;
            break;
        case "option3":
            if(questions[index].options.option3 === true)
                questions[index].options.option3 = false;
            else questions[index].options.option3 = true;
            break;
        default:
    }

    this.props.handleRadioSelect(e);

    this.setState({
        radioQuestions: questions
    });
}

handleRadioTextChange(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;

    const questions = this.state.radioQuestions.slice()
    questions[this.props.index].text = value;

    this.setState({
        radioQuestions: questions
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <input type="radio" name="option1"
                  value="option1"
                  onChange = { this.state.handleRadioSelect }
                  defaultChecked={ this.state.radioQuestions[this.props.index].options.option1 } /> Option 1<br />
            <input type="radio" name="option2"
                  value="option2"
                  onChange = { this.state.handleRadioSelect }
                  defaultChecked={ this.state.radioQuestions[this.props.index].options.option2 } /> Option 2<br />
            <input type="radio" name="option3"
                  value="option3"
                  onChange = { this.state.handleRadioSelect }
                  defaultChecked={ this.state.radioQuestions[this.props.index].options.option3 } /> Option 3<br />
            <textarea rows="1" cols="40" id="answer" name="answer"
                className ="form-control input-default"
                onChange={ this.state.handleRadioTextChange }
                defaultValue = { this.state.radioQuestions[this.props.index].text } />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Repeated code (which is both in the parent and child) was from my attempts to solve the problem. Finally here is the Text input form component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        textAnswers: this.props.textQuestions,
    };

    this.handleTextQuestionChange = this.handleTextQuestionChange.bind(this);
}

handleTextQuestionChange(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;

    const answers = this.state.textAnswers.slice()
    answers[this.props.index] = value;

    this.props.handleTextQuestionChange(e);

    this.setState({
        textAnswers: answers
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="answer" name="answer"
                className ="form-control input-default" onChange = { this.state.handleTextQuestionChange  }
                defaultValue = { this.state.textAnswers[this.props.index] } />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Would also appreciate any additional advice in case I am not following good practices, thank you.

Comment: I think I see a solution, and it seems quite simple, but could you make a snippet or a CodePen to make it a bit easier to work with?

Comment: Also, @Mark20, can you paste here the `render` method of the `App` component?

Comment: @0xc14m1z here is a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/4x5x6oo054

Comment: Thank you @Mark20, I forked the codesandbox and working on it. Hope you don't mind a bit of refactoring :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, and working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/21q3j32qyy
In order to understand where was the problem, I refactored a lot of things and removed duplicated code.

Long answer below...

#### First, a recap of the problem

We have an object that should come from an API or whatever that contains a list of questions for the user and one or to additional information like the survey title.

Right now, sample data are retrieved in `App.js` with:

```
var data = require("./payload.json");
```

Legitimate, even if, using ES6, it could be written (for consistency with the rest of the code) this way:

```
import data from "./payload.json"
```

Watching into the `payload.json` file, is it possible to see that there are 3 possible types of questions:

1. with 3 options that behaves like checkboxes (even if in your code they are radios) and text;
2. with just text;
3. with an image uploader;

A question contains also the text to be prompted to the user, the id and the type to distinguish them.

The user should also be able to navigate through his/her answers.

#### The goal

It seemed to me that you basically... needed this form to work and keep al the answers from the user in state (I imagine that you should send them to an API some time).

#### App.js

This is the main component of the application, or at least of the sample.

Here we should:

1. take/process questions retrieved from somewhere;
2. render the current question;
3. being able to navigate through the questions;
4. handle the answers of the users;

In your constructor you do something that seems strange to me (of course, if instead it's correct for some reason, let me know): you cycle through every question in the data variable and create two separate arrays, one for text questions and one for radio questions, keeping in both fake elements when the question is of the other type...

I thought, instead, to create a unique array of empty answers, with different fields for each type of question. So I created an `Answers.js` file where to handle few things.

First, I have constants holding the fields (and their default values) for the various types of questions:

```
// Answers.js    

const RADIO_FIELDS = {
  options: {
    option1: false,
    option2: false,
    option3: false
  }
};

const TEXT_FIELDS = {
  text: ""
};

const UPLOAD_FIELDS = {
  file: "",
  imageUrl: ""
};
```

I also created another file `Question.js` in which I define some utility constants to deal with question types defined in your data:

```
// Question.js

export const RADIO_QUESTION_TYPE = "RadioQuestion";
export const TEXT_QUESTION_TYPE = "TextQuestion";
export const UPLOAD_QUESTION_TYPE = "FileUpload";

export const QuestionTypes = {
  RADIO: RADIO_QUESTION_TYPE,
  TEXT: TEXT_QUESTION_TYPE,
  UPLOAD: UPLOAD_QUESTION_TYPE
};
```

Settled utilities up, in the `Answers.js` file I created a method that returns an "answer template" plain object starting from a question. To get the result, I just check the question type and merge some common fields with the dedicated ones of the question type:

```
// Answers.js

const fromQuestion = question => {
  const baseAnswer = {
    id: question.id,
    type: question.question_type
  };

  switch (question.question_type) {
    case QuestionTypes.RADIO:
      return Object.assign({}, baseAnswer, RADIO_FIELDS, TEXT_FIELDS);
    case QuestionTypes.TEXT:
      return Object.assign({}, baseAnswer, TEXT_FIELDS);
    case QuestionTypes.UPLOAD:
      return Object.assign({}, baseAnswer, UPLOAD_FIELDS);
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

Here I took a decision about handling unknown type of questions: returning null in the default case of the switch will filter these questions from being displayed.

Again, I wrote a super small utility method that does this check:

```
// Answers.js

const isValid = answer => answer !== null;
```

A the end, a method maps from all questions, to all (valid) "answers templates", and then it is exported like a plain object (just because I like the syntax that we'll get in `App.js` component when we'll use this method):

```
// Answers.js

const from = questions =>
  (questions || []).map(fromQuestion).filter(isValid);

export default {
  from
};
```

At this point, we can import Answers.js in App.js and setting the state variable this way:

```
// App.js

...
import Answers from './Answers';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    answers: Answers.from(data.questions),
    index: 0
  };

  ...
```

We'll have this object inside the `answers` property:

```
[
  {
    id: 2501,
    type: "RadioQuestion",
    options: {
      option1: false,
      option2: false,
      option3: false
    },
    text: ""
  }, {
    id: 2447,
    type: "TextQuestion",
    text: ""
  }, {
  ...
```

Good, we have our data structure and a clean way to get it from our raw data.

Now we have to properly render a question. In your code happens this:

```
// App.js, render method

...

render() {

  const question = () => {
    switch (data.questions[this.state.index].question_type) {
      case "RadioQuestion":
        return (
          <RadioQuestion
            radioQuestion={this.state.radioQuestions[this.state.index]}
            handleRadio={this.handleRadio}
          />
        );
      case "TextQuestion":
        return (
          <TextQuestion
            textQuestion={this.state.textQuestions[this.state.index]}
            handleText={this.handleText}
          />
        );
      case "FileUpload":
        return <FileUpload index={this.state.index} />;
      default:
        return <h2>Unknown Question Format</h2>;
    }
  };

  return (

  ...
  </label>

  { question() }

  <div className="form-group input-margin-top">
  ...
```

You are executing a method that generates some content to be rendered... it's nothing more than a component!

So, to do it in the React way, in the `Question.js` file I defined a Question component similar to the your one:

```
// Question.js

const Question = ({ type, ...props }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case RADIO_QUESTION_TYPE:
      return <RadioQuestion {...props} />;
    case TEXT_QUESTION_TYPE:
      return <TextQuestion {...props} />;
    case UPLOAD_QUESTION_TYPE:
      return <FileUpload {...props} />;
    default:
      return <h1>Unknown Question Format</h1>;
  }
};

export default Question;
```

I destructure the type prop and render a different component just passing down all the other props.

TO BE CONTINUED WITH EDITS (I'm afraid to lose everything!)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main issue here is that your state is holding an array with objects, which are not being cloned using `Array.slice` function. Notice that this function is only shallow-copying the array so that the objects inside it remain the same between state transitions.

I recommend using [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) for handling state mutations of deep objects.